# How to set wlm_query_slot_count using Spark-Redshift connector

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am using the spark-redshift connector in order to launch a query from Spark.

```
val results = spark.sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
      .option("url", url_connection)
      .option("query", query)
      .option("aws_iam_role", iam_role)
      .option("tempdir", base_path_temp)
      .load()
```

I would like to increase the slot count in order to improve the query, because is disk-based. But I don't know how to do the next query in the connector:

```
set wlm_query_slot_count to 3;
```

I don't see how to do this , since in the read command in the connector doesn't provide preactions and postactions like in the write command.

Thanks

Comment: You are right, you cannot do this. However you could use a specific user id and a related WLM group with more slots?

Comment: You can do that, but if I want more memory for a specific query, even if I have a group with more slots, how can I assign those slots to the query? Because if I am not wrong the query will use only one slot by default.... if you want to assign more you need to set it manually: set wlm_query_slot_count to 3;  @JonScott